# Start Unified Remote Server before login using systemd service

Tags: debian, systemd

I am currently trying to run [Unified Remote Server](https://www.unifiedremote.com/) before login. (Need to use it to login)

I have managed to have it running after login, so it works generally.

This is my `systemd` `.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=Unified Remote Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Group=sudo
Environment=HOME=~
Environment=OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/
ExecStart=/opt/urserver/urserver-start --no-manager --no-notify
ExecStop=/opt/urserver/urserver-stop

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

### Error Output

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/urserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-07-17 01:07:06 EDT; 1h 52min ago

urserver-start[8014]: 140156550736640:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
urserver-start[8014]: 140156550736640:error:0E07506E:configuration file routines:MODULE_LOAD_DSO:error loading dso:conf_mod.c:285:module=ssl_
urserver-start[8014]: 140156550736640:error:0E076071:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:unknown module name:conf_mod.c:222:module=ssl_con
urserver-start[8014]: skipping manager
urserver-stop[8032]: cat: /.urserver/urserver.pid: No such file or directory
urserver-stop[8032]: process not detected
urserver-stop[8032]: rm: cannot remove '/.urserver/urserver.pid': No such file or directory
systemd[1]: urserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: urserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Unified Remote Server.
```

It seems I have 2 errors

1. From the `cat: /.urserver/urserver.pid: No such file or directory` line, I assume the `$HOME` environment variable is not resolving properly.
2. It seems that some dependencies might not be loaded yet, how do I ensure that it is?

Answer (score 2):

On Raspberry Pi 4B with Buster, I had different errors trying to start `urserver` as a `systemd` service.
May not at all be related to your problems.

This worked for me:
I think the key was to exit the start script with exit 0 to make systemd ignore the errors triggered by `triggerhappy`.

urserver.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unified Remote Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/opt/urserver/urserver-start --no-notify
ExecStop=/opt/urserver/urserver-stop
SyslogIdentifier=urserver

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

urserver-start:

```
#!/bin/sh


#
# Path to installation directory
#
EXEC_PATH="/opt/urserver/urserver"
PID_PATH="$HOME/.urserver/urserver.pid"
ICON_PATH="/usr/share/icons/hicolor/96x96/apps/urserver.png"
REMOTES_PATH="$HOME/.urserver/remotes"
BACKUP_PATH="$HOME/.urserver/backup"


#
# Check arguments
#
NO_COPY=false
NO_MANAGER=false
NO_NOTIFY=false

for var in "$@"
do
       if [ "$var" = "--no-copy" ]; then
               NO_COPY=true
       elif [ "$var" = "--no-manager" ]; then
               NO_MANAGER=true
       elif [ "$var" = "--no-notify" ]; then
               NO_NOTIFY=true
       fi
done


#
# Copy user files
#
if ! "$NO_COPY" = true; then
   echo "copying user files"
   mkdir -p "$HOME/.config/autostart/"
   cp -uf /opt/urserver/urserver-autostart.desktop $HOME/.config/autostart/urserver.desktop

   echo "backup remotes"
   mkdir -p $BACKUP_PATH/
   cp -af $REMOTES_PATH/. $BACKUP_PATH/

   echo "create custom folder"
   mkdir -p $REMOTES_PATH/custom/

   echo "copying remotes"
   rm -rf $REMOTES_PATH/remotes/
   rm -rf $REMOTES_PATH/bundled/
   mkdir -p $REMOTES_PATH/bundled/
   cp -af /opt/urserver/remotes/. $REMOTES_PATH/bundled/
else
   echo "skipping copy"
fi


#
# Start the server
#
echo "starting server"
mkdir -p "$HOME/.urserver"
$EXEC_PATH --remotes=$REMOTES_PATH --daemon


#
# Open the web manager
#
if ! "$NO_MANAGER" = true; then
   echo "opening manager"
   sleep 1
   xdg-open http://localhost:9510/web 2> /dev/null
else
   echo "skipping manager"
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by deleting `Environment=HOME=~`.

`systemd` automatically sets `$HOME` so you never need to specify it unless you want it to be non-default.  When the user is `root`, I think `$HOME` will probably be set to `/root`. Also, `~` is something that is a `sh` shortcut for the home directory, but outside of your shell it doesn't mean anything.  `systemd` is not `sh` and does not support all of the `sh` syntax.  You'll also notice things like `&&` or `|` will not work in `ExecStart=`.

Removing the `Environment=` line may fix all of your issues. But if not, here are some other things to look for:

---

```
User=root
Group=sudo
```

This one is a little strange.  `User=root` is already implied when it's run in the system bus, so it's redundant.  I could only see `Group=sudo` being useful in that new files may be created owned by the `sudo` group, though that is probably only interesting if `root` is actually a member of `sudo` and your default `umask` creates new files as group-readable/writable.  I think you can delete these, though it may not make a massive difference.

---

Since your service is `Type=forking`, consider adding:

```
PIDFile=/root/.urserver/urserver.pid
```

this will help systemd reliably identify the main process of the service

---

The `DSO_load` errors indicate that your application can't dynamically load a module. The message looks truncated but related to `ssl`.

When I look up `man openssl`, I see that the `OPENSSL_CONF` variable should point to the configuration file, not the directory containing the configuration file. Try deleting this line or using something like:

```
Environment=OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Note that this is probably the default location, so the variable probably doesn't need to be set.

Comment: Ok will try that